# Как сделать, чтобы телеграм-бот не отвечал на каждое фото из групповые списка?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, api, telegram, telebot

Есть бот, который отвечает на каждое фото/изображение, но если прислать сразу группу фото (скажем 5 шт), то бот возвращает сразу 5 ответов подряд (А нужно, чтоб только 1 ответ на одну группу). Как можно это пофиксить? (**для pyTelegramBotAPI**)

Додумался только до этого:

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo', 'files'])

def messages(message):
    if message.media_group_id:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="ОТВЕТ")
        return() 

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     bot.infinity_polling()
```

Я понимаю, что для айди группы нужно формировать хранилище или вроде того, но как сделать не знаю. Я совсем новичок еще.

Comment: `return` добавьте

Comment: Уже пробовал. Это не работает. Т.к. обработчик сначала выполняет "Ответить на все файлы, где есть "media_group_id" (одинкаовый id присваивается ко всем групповым файлам), а уже потом код останавливается.

Comment: Весь код выложите хотя бы, тут гадать сложно, в чём проблема

Comment: Не в комментарии, а в вопрос. Для этого есть кнопка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1330591/edit)

Comment: @MyZik исправил

Answer (score 0):

Это правильное поведение. В Bot API нет понятия входящий альбом. Есть только костыли, чтобы пытаться их обрабатывать цельным куском. Как  вариант каждый раз при получении сохранять message.media_group_id куда-нибудь (допустим в Redis) и делать проверку чтобы ответное сообщение не отправлялся на этот альбом несколько раз